# How to run go vet on all code regardless of platform

Tags: go

When I run `go vet ./...` to check my project it only checks source code matching the current platform and architecture. E.g. suppose I have:

```
example.go
example_darwin.go
example_windows.go
example_linux.go
example_linux_amd64.go
example_linux_arm64.go
```

If I'm on my Mac and I run `go vet ./...` then it will only look at `example.go` and `example_darwin.go` but it won't vet the Windows or Linux files.

If I want to vet everything I *could* just invoke it over and over again for every combination:

```
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go vet ./...
GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go vet ./...
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go vet ./...
GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 go vet ./...
```

That seems a bit excessive. Is there any straightforward way to vet all the code in one pass without re-vetting some files many times over? Is that even a meaningful thing to do, or is vetting inherently a "whole package" operation?

Comment: vet runs the type checker, so it's probably not possible to run it for all architectures at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking it over and over again is the only way to do this.  The reason is that `go vet` does type and symbol resolution, so it's possible that any given file may vet cleanly for one architecture, but not for another.

The best you may be able to do is to programatically execute all of the various `go vet` statements for the available build tags. I have not tried this, but [`go list`](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/internal/list/)'s `-format` flag may be able to provide this list of tags for you, to feed into such a script.